# Mvvmcross: launching an android dialog containing a ListView

Tags: android, mvvm, dialog, xamarin, mvvmcross

First, I will like to give a big Kudos to Stuart Lodge for this awesome framework. Together with Xamarin's Visual Studio integration, this is one of the most productive cross platform frameworks I have laid my hands on.

What I want to achieve is launch a dialog containing a selectable ListView when a button is clicked.  I need access to the selected item when the user closes this dialog.  Is there a recommended way to do this using the Mvvmcross' dialog plugin while following the MVVM paradigm?

I am using the following Activity to create a dialog.

```
[Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog")]
    public class SearchResultDialogView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SearchResultView);
        }
    }
```

Navigating to `SearchResultDialogViewModel` from another view model brings up this view as modal. So it looks like I am heading in the right direction.  However,  the dialog is  missing the OK and Cancel buttons and I will also like to get rid of the default header.  Think I need an AlertDialog but so far I have had no success launching one with this code:

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class SearchResultDialogView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args)
        {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetTitle("some title");
            return builder.Create();
        }
    }
```

Apologies if this question is vague.  I am new to Android UI development.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different uses of the word dialog here.

- Android Dialogs are 'popup displays' and are covered in http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html
- The MvvmCross Dialog plugin is a code-based form-builder forked from the existing MonoDroid.Dialog and MonoTouch.Dialog tools - see https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog
- The Holo Dialog display is (actually I'm not sure) some theme-based skin on a normal `Activity`.

With these in mind...

If you want to display a general popup window to collect some data, then you can try using a fragment based dialog to collect data - this is demonstrated (with a little code behind) in [Fragments HomeView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/HomeView.cs) with [NameDialogFragment.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/Frags/Dialog/NameDialogFragment.cs) - for general background on fragments, watch N=26 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

If you want to use a separate activity for data collection, then @gschackles wrote this article on one way of returning data from child viewmodels - http://www.gregshackles.com/2012/11/returning-results-from-view-models-in-mvvmcross/ - I'm sure other schemes could also be used.

If you do want to learn about the Mvx Dialog plugin, see N=23 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  Will look into these alternatives.  Again, your framework is top notch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the builder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

The code is:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color);
           .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

and you can get your element by returning the `which` value to your caller.

Comment: Looks like this is similar to what I am doing above, although I am not populating the dialog's content area.